# how to read file from incoming request without saving it to local disk using node.js express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have my back-end `server` in `express(node.js)` and all `apis` is running on this `server`. I also have `file-upload` mechanism for `file-upload` `api` using `multer`. For file uploading i have created a `middleware` and in my `helper` `controller` i have this

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    let path = getFileStoragePath(req, file);
    console.log(`path to create ${path}`)
        // let path = `uploads/transId${req.body.refrenceId}/transporter`
    checkDirectory(path, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Error occured if checkDirectory ${err.message}`)
            cb(err, null)
        } else {
            cb(null, path);
        }
    });
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    let dateNow = new Date()
    cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${dateformat(dateNow, 'dddd_mmmm_dS_yyyy_h_MM_ss_TT')}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
 }
});

const saveFilesToFolder = async(req, res, next) => {
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: imageFilter,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10
    }
}).any();

upload(req, res, (err) => {
    const wasValidRequest = checkAllowedFiles(req);

    if (wasValidRequest.status === false) {
        return res.send({
            status: false,
            message: wasValidRequest.message,
            response: null
        })
    }

    // counter = 0
    if (err) {
        console.log(`Error uploading files, ${err.message}`)
        return res.send({
            status: false,
            message: `Error occurred while uploading files, ${err.message}`,
            response: null
        })
    }

    // WHEN FILE UPLOADING IS DONE NOW PASSING THE REQUEST
    next();
 });
};
```

And in my `route.js` file i have attached my `middleware` to save `files` into folder and reading `files` like this

```
router.post('/upload-files', saveFilesToFolder, catchAsyncErrors(fileController.UploadFiles));
```

but now my requirement is that i want to read the `content` of `file` which is coming in `incoming request`without saving that file to local `disk` by accessing the file inside my `fileController` `function` and i want to make a separate api for this purpose?

How can i do this

Comment: You can store it in local and then read it in controller, after that you can delete the file

Comment: is there any method though which i prevent my `api` to do these redundant steps(saving to local and then deleting after reading it)

Comment: We can do that i just read the doc, i add it in answers

Comment: can you refer me any of that answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My requirement was to use `multer` milddleware inside of my `controller` function to `access/read` incoming file from `request`. So i have achieved that and i am giving an answer for future readers so i did like this

controller.js

```
var storage = multer.memoryStorage({
   destination: function(req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, '');
   }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any();


const saveFilesToS3 = async(req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, async(err) => {
        console.log(req.files[0].buffer) // printing incoming file content as buffer
        // rest of the code here 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multer provide memory options by which without storing file in local system, we can convert it into buffer and read the content.

Refer [this](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#memorystorage) or [this](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-multer/build/apidoc.html#apidoc.element.multer.memoryStorage)

```
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/imagenes', upload.single('image_field'), function(req,res){

        req.file.buffer;
});
```

In controller you can use

```
console.log(String(req.file.buffer))
```

to look into content

Comment: I didn't find any example where they are converting file into buffer and then reading that file in api controller function

Comment: I will check for example

Comment: @FahadSubzwari https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/198 here they are using it check it out

Comment: My problem is that i don't want to create `multer` `storage` and all that in my `route.js`. I want to do this all stuf in my `controller` `function` so how can i achieve that?

Comment: As i read through everyone is using formidable or multer to accesss incoming files.

Comment: yes i also want to read file through `multer` but i am asking that how can i use this `upload.single('image_field')` inside my controller because i don't want to create this `var storage = multer.memoryStorage();` and this `var upload = multer({ storage: storage });` inside of my `route.js` file because i am keeping my `api routes` separate from all implementation

Comment: You can create a new middleware which will return multer({storage: multer.memoryStorage()}); and use it in routes instead of old one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with buffer, converting buffer to file another job needs to be done. You can basicly use **os.tmpdir()**

```
const os = require('os');
const multerObject = multer({ dest: os.tmpdir() });
multerObject.single('file')
```